# Sum with binomial coefficients and fraction $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k \frac{1}{k+c}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

Is there a closed form known for

$$
\phi(n,a,c)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k \frac{1}{k+c} 
$$

where $a <0$, $c>0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I know the answer for two special cases:

$$ 
\phi(n,a,1)= \frac{(1+a)^{n+1}-1}{a(n+1)}, \qquad \phi(n,-1,c)=\frac{n! \Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(n+1+c)},
$$
where $\Gamma$ denotes the Gamma function. But what about the general case? If there is no closed form, do we know anything about the asymptotic behaviour for large $n$?

Comment: According  to Mathematica it is  Gamma[c] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[c, -n, 1 + c, -a] . You get a nice expression with $a=-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can try is

$$a^c \phi(n,a,c) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{a^{k+c}}{k+c}$$

Now differentiate with respect to $a$:

$$\frac{\partial }{\partial a}[a^c \phi(n,a,c)] = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^{k+c-1} = a^{c-1} (a+1)^n$$

The next step is to integrate both sides; the right-hand side is tougher than it looks for general $c$:

$$a^c \phi(n,a,c)=\int da \: a^{c-1} (a+1)^n = \frac{a^c \, _2F_1(c,-n;c+1;-a)}{c} + K$$

where $K$ is a constant of integration and is zero.  Therefore

$$\phi(n,a,c) = \frac{_2F_1(c,-n;c+1;-a)}{c}$$

Comment: many thanks, this solved my problem!

Comment: You're welcome.  Please remember to accept the solution by clicking on the checkmark if you found the solution useful.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(n,a,c)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^k \frac{1}{k+c}$,
$x^c f(n,a,c)=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^{k+c} \frac{1}{k+c}$.

Differentiating,
and writing $f$ for $f(n, a, c)$,
$x^c f' + c x^{c-1} f = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^{k+c-1}
= x^{c-1} \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} a^{k}
= x^{c-1} (1+a)^n
$
or 
$x f' + c f =(1+x)^n$
or
$f' + c f/x = (1+x)^n/x$.

Trying to integrate this
probable leads to either the original series
(if you try to find a power series solution)
or to the hypergeometric function
described by clink31.